# Is it allowed to pull a stochastic variable/process outside the integral?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If we encounter an integral of the form:

$I=\int\limits_0^t X(s)y(s)ds$, where $X(s)$ is a stochastic (variable or process) and $y(s)$ is a deterministic function, say $e^{as}$. I want to know under what conditions can we pull out the $X(s)$ outside the integral and write the solution as:

$I=X(s) \frac{[e^{at}-e^0]}{a}$

Comment: What does your final equation mean? The left side does not depend on $s$ but the right side does?

Comment: You might be able to represent your $X$ in terms of some function basis, say sin/cos, and then evaluate the integral

Comment: @Cryo Thanks. I just named the integral as $I$. So representing $X$ in terms of a particular basis means defining its density, and then integrating? So in principle there is no way to factor $X(s)$ outside the integral under $any$ assumption other than assuming it to be constant?

Comment: You still did not reply what you meant by left-hand side not depending on $s$ and right-hand side depending. In your first equation, which we can treat as definition of $I$, it manifestly does not depend on $s$, but in the last one $I$ is made equal to something that does depend on $s$. How do you imagine this to work? Equivalently, if both your last and your first equation are correct, then $X$ must be constant, I don't even need to know much about the integral (it suffices to know it is not zero)

Comment: @Cryo Thanks. My question is straightforward, I want to know whether you can pull $X(s)$ outside the integral or not? Forget about $I$. lets see it this way $\int\limits_0^t X(s)y(s)ds$. I have seen somewhere that it is possible if $X$ is a R.V and not possible if it is a Stochastic process. under what conditions it is allowed to do so.

Comment: If $\int^t X\left(s\right)y\left(s\right)ds=X\left(s\right)\cdot f\left(t\right)$ for some $f=f\left(t\right)\neq 0$ then $X\left(s\right)$ cannot depend on $s$ and thus must be constant.

Comment: The only loophoole I can see is for $X$ to be zero almost everywhere with respect to measure $s$ and $y$ to be zero on all measureable subsets (so that RHS integral would be zero)

Comment: @Cryo The ideas are basically right, but there exist exceptions.  As a very simple example, let $X_t$ be a time series process on $\Theta=\{0,1,2\ldots,\}$ defined by a random variable $X_0$ with $X_t=(-1)^t X_0$ for all $t\ge 0.$  When $-\infty\lt\sum_{s=0}^\infty y(2s)=\sum_{s=0}^\infty y(2s+1)\lt\infty$ the integral is always zero but $X_t$ is nontrivial and the support of $y$ is $\Theta.$ If that's unsatisfactory because the parameter space is discrete, let $X_t$ be a periodic process on $\mathbb R:$ you can find plenty of $y$ to make the integral almost surely zero.

Comment: @whuber agree. You can construct exceptions. Not something on would expect so seein the wild though